# How To Handle Drag And Drop Event In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using JavaScript and don't know how to handle the  drag and drop event. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

```
    /* events fired on the draggable target */
    document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {

    }, false);

    /* events fired on the drop targets */
    document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {

    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {

    }, false);
```